# Is there any function for changing the operation by pressing different buttons

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to show up a cross in the middle of my screen and change the size of it pressing some keys on my keyboard.

For example ,
if I press b , the cross should become big.
if I press s, the cross should become small.
if I press m, the cross should become medium.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    while(true)
    {

        Mat frame;
        // Capture frame-by-frame
        cap >> frame;

        // If the frame is empty, break immediately
        if (frame.empty())
            break;
        // for converting the frame to grayscale  
        Mat gray;
        cvtColor( frame, gray , COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        line( frame, Point( 300, 240 ), Point( 340,240), Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ),  2, 4 );
        line( frame, Point( 320, 260), Point( 320, 220), Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 2, 4);
        imshow(" figure ",frame);

        char c=(char)waitKey(25);
        if(c==27)
            break;
    }

    cap.release();
    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

please help me with this

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please include some of your code so people here have something to work on, especially how you initiate your cross and, if you made any, your attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: hey, I added my code....please look into my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposition is to introduce 'scale' variable that will be modified by key presses to calculate start and end points for both lines. Just assume those points are defined as `[start point] = [middle point] - [scale] * [scale factor]` and `[end point] = [middle point] + [scale] * [scale factor]`. So it would look like:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
int size = 2;
bool drawCross = 1;
while(true)
{

    Mat frame;
    // Capture frame-by-frame
    cap >> frame;

    // If the frame is empty, break immediately
    if (frame.empty())
        break;
    // for converting the frame to grayscale  
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor( frame, gray , COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    if (drawCross) {
        line( frame, Point( 320 - 10*size, 240 ), Point( 320 + 10*size,240), Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ),  2, 4 );
        line( frame, Point( 320, 240 - 10*size), Point( 320, 240 + 10*size), Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 2, 4);
    }
    imshow(" figure ",frame);

    char c=(char)waitKey(25);
    if(c==27)
        break;
    else if (c==[whatever this "small" key is])
        size = 1;
    else if (c==[whatever this "medium" key is])
        size = 2;
    else if (c==[whatever this "large" key is])
        size = 4;
    else if (c==[whatever this "do not draw cross" key is])
        drawCross = !drawCross;
}
```

==EDIT==
Solution is now fixed to be working with new 'requirements' given in comments below. This is my last input on this question, as SO is not 'Can you write that for me?' type of community. Your problems described in comments required me up to two minutes of googl-ing. And you need to read up on programming **basics** before you go on, like conditional branching and stuff. And I do not know if this code works 100% as I don't want to install C++ compiler at this moment.

Comment: Ah, forgive me for my Python syntax mixin, now fixed :)

Comment: how to give the command in the else if condition  else if (c==[whatever this "small" key is]), ie what should I add in c==[ ]?

Comment: the same how you found out what key 27 is. You choose whichever key you want, then gogle 'character [you have chosen] key code'

Comment: Try `(c==(int)'c')`

Comment: hey i want to on and off the cross, im trying to put up a if condition but the code is crashing....

Comment: i tried to make the size = 0 but after doing this it shows a point in the middle but i want it to completely go off.

Comment: size is not relative size but rather 'ratio' for calculating endpoints. You should introduce boolean, f.e. `draw_cross` and then do `if draw_cross { [draw your cross as usual]; }`

Comment: 'if (draw_cross)
  {
        line( frame, Point( 320 - 10*size, 240 ), Point( 320 + 10*size,240), Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ),  2, 4 );
        line( frame, Point( 320, 240 - 10*size), Point( 320, 240 + 10*size), Scalar( 0, 0, 255 ), 2, 4);'

Comment: I introduced a boolean by bool draw_cross and then i used if (draw_cross)

Comment: but then whats the use of adding the boolean?

Comment: When you detect a key press you set your boolean variable to True/False, and then, in the next loop, you check if said variable has been switched on or off and decide to draw the cross or not...

Comment: bool draw_cross = true;
  if (draw_cross)
  {
  char c=(char)waitKey(25);
    if(c==27)
        break;
    else if (c==97)
        size = 1;
    else if (c==98)
        size = 2;
    else if (c==99)
        size = 4;
   else if (c==0x30)
        size = 0;

Comment: I'm so sorry that I irritated you....im a begineer to c++ and i didnt know how to work on boolean datatype, im working on my project without any help. So thank you so much for ur help.